# React axios JSON.stringify() use to [Object object] -> "[Object object]"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

i'm junior fronted developer, and i want to your help...

below my pages code

```
  const sendAnotherIp = async () => {
    const domain_format = /^(((http(s?))\:\/\/)?)([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\:[0-9]+)?(\/\S*)?/;

    if (domain_format.test(anotherIp)) {
      await axios
        .get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_URL}/api/dnslookup`, {
          params: {
            search: anotherIp,
            date: nowTime,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          alert(res.data);
        });
    } else {
      alert("it's wrong domain format");
    }
  };

  console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); -> "[Object object]"
```

below my api code

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const dns = require("dns");

interface Iquerys {
  search: string;
  date: string;
}

interface IUrl {
  ip: string;
}

const dnslookup = (request: NextApiRequest, response) => {
  const req = response.req;

  const querys: Iquerys = req.query;

  const searchData = querys.search;
  const dateData = querys.date;


// below my logic
  response.status(200).end(
    `${dns.resolveAny(searchData, function (err: any, addresses: any) {
      return addresses;
    })}`
  );
//

  // db connect
  let db = new sqlite3.Database("./db/my_database.db", (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err.message);
    }
    console.log("Connected to database!");
  });

  // db peristalsis
  db.run("INSERT INTO DnsLookup(search, date) VALUES (?, ?)", [searchData, dateData], (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err.message);
    }
    console.log("Row was added to the table: ${this.lastID}");
  });
};

export default dnslookup;
```

my project build in react, next js.
I used to JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() and toString() ... etc
but I can't find a way to real data.
what's wrong with my code? help me please guys

Comment: @innocent this makes no sense at all. `RegExp#test` does not return a promise. And you don't await things that "take time", only things that produce a promise. Moreover, regex doesn't take that much time, unless the pattern itself is wrong and, for example, introduces catastrophic backtracking. *Even then*, if the pattern testing takes time, it still just blocks, doesn't produce a promise. Can't be awaited.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys (@VLAZ and @Reyno) but had similar problem a while back and using await helped it so was suggesting it to try and check

Comment: thanks for your advice! but my critical problem is JSON.stringify() is not working... how i can fixed it this logic?

Comment: @innocent then *at best* it worked by accident. Or maybe it didn't at all and you thought it did. Or maybe the situation is not even the same. Slapping random awaits aimlessly is not a useful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the server code is the problem. You should wait for the call back to complete then you should send the response.

```
response.status(200).end(
    `${dns.resolveAny(searchData, function (err: any, addresses: any) {
      return addresses;
    })}`
  );
```

On the front end code, you should remove await in front of Axios that is not needed.

Comment: umm.. i think if server code have a problem, in front code returns null or undefined.. isn't it??

Comment: Yes, It could be. You can check it in the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

First declare the headers to be Application/Json

axios.get('m', {
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
})

Comment: i'll do your follow, but same problem....